# How do I pause the output of minicom?

Tags: terminal, minicom

What is the key combination to pause/freeze the output of minicom?

At times the output scrolls very quickly and it makes it difficult to analyse some event.

I know I could instead capture to a file but I would really prefer to be able to just pause.

Comment: Can you use screen's or tmux's scrollback functionality?  That's how I normally do it.

Comment: Yeah, I'd also use `screen` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just realised Ctrl+A by itself pauses minicom printing to the screen. Press Esc to continue.

Answer (score 4):

Software flow-control or XON/XOFF is what you are looking for.

`Ctrl-S` (XOFF) will pause output.  `Ctrl-Q` (XON) will restart it.

For more information, see [Software Flow Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_flow_control)

Comment: So _that_ what it's for! I'd only ever used it to lock a terminal so nothing could be entered.

Answer (score 0):

Just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>. That will pause the current process. You can use `bg` to have it resume in the background and `fg` to make it return to he foreground.

This is not specific to `minicom` it will work for anything that is printing to the terminal. Assuming `minicom` is printing regular output it should work fine for it.

Comment: Ctrl+Z is ignored by minicom. Sorry I didn't mean pause the current process, I meant freeze the output on the screen so I can look at it.

Comment: @austinmarton yeah, that depends on how the process is running. I couldn't test with `minicom` cause I don't have a modem. It works fine with other programs that write to the terminal, freezes the output as expected.

Comment: Just so you know, you can create a named pipe and set it as the serial device in minicom.  It's useful for testing...